# List item created through SPD workflow does not start “when a new item created” workflow

Tags: 2007, workflow

For some reason my workflow (Workflow A) designed in SPD to start when a new item is created does not start when a new item is created in another SPD workflow using the "Create List Item" action.

**My scenario is:***

Workflow A - configured to start when a new item is created in List A: Creates a new list item in List B.

Workflow B - configured to start when a new item is created in List B: Creates a new list item in List A

**When I test this i get the following:**

I manually create a list item in List A. 
Workflow A fires and creates a new list item in List B. 
Workflow B fires and creates a new list item in List A. 
But Workflow A **does not fire** on the new item in List A.

### ---**edit**-----
Is this happening because the item created in List A by Workflow B is created by System Account thus not firing Workflow A?

I think
----------------**edit**-----------------------------------

I am aware this is causes an infinite loop there is a pause for duration action set to 1 year in workflow A. So it fires in yearly cycles.

I know sp2 prevents infinite loops being created on the same list but from what i read of the article below suggests this is possible to do cross lists as in my scenario.
[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/service-pack-2-prevents-an-on-change-workflow-from-starting-itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create an infinate loop on the same list, if you like. Just use two workflows (firing on create and edit) on a list with one yes or no field (defaulted to No, or Yes - shouldnt matter in this case) that the workflows can toggle back and fourth to trigger eachother.

Workflow One action: wait for yes/no field to equal Yes and then Set field value of yes/no field to No

Workflow Two action: wait for yes/no field to equal No and then Set field value of yes/no field to Yes

This should cause an infinate loop on a list item using 2 workflows that trigger eachother back and fourth. You can also do this in a more controlled way by adding a counter that adds to itself with each loop so that after 30 loops, the counter will equal 30, after 40 loops, counter equals 40, etc... You can then set a workflow condition that stops the back and fourth triggering at Count = X

A lot more ways to get creative with this, but you can loop a workflow in sharepoint just like any language.

Answer (score 2):

I'd hate to point out the obvious but I'm assuming there's a reasoning behind your logic:

That will start an infinite loop, you realise?

Comment: Fair point its an infinite loops I want :)

Comment: edited question with explaination

Comment: Is Sharepoint clever enough (I'm hoping not) to detect and prevent this?

Comment: I don't think it is to be honest (though others here might know more) - have you had a look at the Workflow History List to see if there's any info on what's happening, if anything at all? If you have access o the ULS Log there also might be some clues as to why the Workflow A is refusing to start the second time...

Comment: Thanks - since the workflow doesn't start there is no workflow history but I can confirm the item is created but the workflow doesnt start. I checked the ULS logs but there are no error or information i can decipher from it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mixing things up a bit and manually creating the first item in List B to see if it still stops at the same point?

Answer (score 0):

Or u can start the WorkFlow dynamicly, since SPD 2010 workflows have a kind of security which will prevent infinite loops.

Add an event receiver (item added) and start the workflow there.

I am guessing this will work.